# Very Deep Convolutional Networks for Text Classification: Clarifying skip connections

Tags: deep-learning, cnn

Question RE this research paper if anyone has experience with CNN's, pooling & skip connections: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1606.01781.pdf

- In figure 1, the input to the first convolutional block has shape (batch_size, 64, s)
- The output from block 1 must be (batch_size, 64, s)
- The output from block 2 must be (batch_size, 64, s)

However the output from the pooling step has shape (batch_size, 128, s/2). How can a pooling step increase the number of parameters on axis 1 from 64 to 128?!

My guess is that the input to the pooling layer is actually a concatenation of 2 of the previous layer's outputs. In this case it would have input shape (batch_size, 128, s). However, the paper does not appear to clearly specify at what outputs are concatenated...

Can anyone clarify how this is the case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you mentioned, the paper doesn't clarify. However, my guess is that this is not due to concatenating 2 previous layers (I don't really see an specific reason to do this here) but because of concatenating the *ResNet shorcut*.

Generally, all conv layers have a number of filters, thus determining the output size (*num_filters*, *size*) regardless the inputs. On the other hand, MaxPooling does keep the input *num_filters* (though in this case reducing the *size*). In the paper, note that the *num_filters* is doubled at the output of all convlayer except for the one that does not keep the *ResNet shorcut* (last 512 conv layer). So my guess is that they are concatenating the output of the conv layer and the shorcut which would explain the output size.

Hope this helps!